# Is there a way to click Navlink from within a function?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Basically, I'm delaying the navigation.

After clicking the Link, the onClick handler prevents the navigation by checking a condition and calls another function. If certain condition is met, then only the page navigates to another.

So how can I trigger Navlink click from within that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by using **event.preventDefault()**.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import Modal from './Modal'

var confirmation = {};

class Example extends Component {

handleClick(event) {
    if(this.props.data.length!=0) {
        confirmation = {
            prompt: (
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col s12 m5"><a className="btn" onClick={this.props.actions.toggleModal()}>No</a></div>
                    <div className="col s12 m7"><NavLink to={"/"+this.props.endpoint+"/1"} activeClassName="active" className="btn"}>Yes, Navigate to Option 1</NavLink></div>
                </div>
            )
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <nav>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col s10">
                        <ul  className="col s12">
                            <li className="col s4 m4 l3"><NavLink to={"/"+this.props.endpoint+"/1"} activeClassName="active" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Option 1</NavLink></li>
                            <li className="col s4 m4 l3"><NavLink to={"/"+this.props.endpoint+"/2"} activeClassName="active">Option 2</NavLink></li>
                            <li className="col s4 m4 l3"><NavLink to={"/"+this.props.endpoint+"/3"} activeClassName="active">Option 3</NavLink></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            {
                this.props.openModal ?
                    <Modal data={confirmation}/>
                    : null
            }
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default example
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the react-router Link component, you can use their API to programmatically navigate to another page (if the certain condition is met).

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  navCheck(nextPage) {
    if (someCondition) {
      this.context.router.history.push(nextPage);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(<a onClick={() => this.navCheck('/next-page')}>Navigate To Another Page</a>);
  }
}

MyComponent.contextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.shape({
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  }),
};
```

More information on the official documentation: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history

Comment: Please note both `Link` and `NavLink` are more complicated than a simple `a` element.